# SASS @if statement using variable name

Tags: if-statement, sass

I'm having an issue generating the correct code with the @if statement based on a variable.

SASS

```
    =band($name, $color)
      .band-#{$name}
        background-color: #{$color}
        @if $name == white
          font-size: 100px
        @else
          font-size: 20px

    +band('white', $white)
    +band('black', $black)
```

to generate

```
    .band-white{background-color:white; font-size:100px;}
    .band-black{background-color:black; font-size:50px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your mixin is comparing the variable that is coming in with a color.

You are passing in the string `'white'` which is not the same as the HTML color `white`.

Have a look at the [SassScript DataTypes](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#data_types).

So, to fix your Sass, you will have to either change your code to

```
=band($name, $color)
  .band-#{$name}
    background-color: #{$color}
    @if $name == 'white'
      font-size: 100px
    @else
      font-size: 20px

+band('white', $white)
+band('black', $black)
```

or

```
=band($name, $color)
  .band-#{$name}
    background-color: #{$color}
    @if $name == white
      font-size: 100px
    @else
      font-size: 20px

+band(white, $white)
+band(black, $black)
```

The latter will not give you anything useful if you pass in anything else than a color as the first argument.

By the way, you could also simplify the condition by using a single-line if in case you are using Sass 3.3 or higher:
`font-size: if($name == white, 100px, 20px)`

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it's a white space issue. Do you get anything useful in the logs?

I was able to get a version of your code working:

```
@mixin band($name) 
  background-color: $name 
  @if $name == white
    font-size: 50px
  @else 
    font-size: 20px

.band-white
  @include band($name: white)

.band-black
  @include band($name: black)
```

And you can see it working here https://codepen.io/sitrobotsit/pen/aWQxNE

Comment: That is quite a different outcome to what @brad is trying to achieve.

Comment: @PatrikAffentranger yes, perhaps I should have asked the reasoning behind the redundant arguments passed. However, the outcome (the compiled CSS) is exactly what the OP was after and achieved in a less verbose manor. So I don't think a down vote is warranted.

Comment: IMO, the outcome is different because @brad wanted to be able to automatically generate the class names based on the first argument. Which is different to writing them out and then using a mixin just for the `background-color`.

Comment: Yeah, ok, fair enough.

Comment: sorry, should've been clearer in my initial comment.